# "Thinking In Java" concurrency CloseResource.java

Tags: java, concurrency, interrupt

I'm reading the book 《thinking In java》(Fouth Edition) and find a question about the source code concurrency/CloseResource.java . When the `socketInput.close()` method throws an InterruptedException, the thread which inputStream is socketInput could terminates normally, however, the other thread which inputStream is System.in couldn't exit. The program can't exit.

Could you give me some reason about this.

```
    class IOBlocked implements Runnable{
private InputStream in ; 
public IOBlocked(InputStream is){
    in=is;
}
public void run(){
    try{
        System.out.println("Waiting for read():");
        in.read();
    }catch(IOException e){
        if(Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()){
            System.out.println("Interrupted from blocked I/O");

        }else{
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
    System.out.println("Exiting IOBlocked.run()");
}   
   }

    public class CloseResource {
     public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
    ExecutorService exec = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();   
    ServerSocket server = new ServerSocket(8080);   
    InputStream socketInput =   
      new Socket("localhost", 8080).getInputStream();   
    exec.execute(new IOBlocked(socketInput));   
    exec.execute(new IOBlocked(System.in));   
    TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.sleep(100);   
    System.out.println("Shutting down all threads");   
    exec.shutdownNow();   
    TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(1);   
    System.out.println("Closing " + socketInput.getClass().getName());   
    socketInput.close(); // Releases blocked thread   
    TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(1);   
    System.out.println("Closing " + System.in.getClass().getName());   
    System.in.close(); // Releases blocked thread   
}
}
```

Comment: Is the resource ever closing? If you try to read to read from System.in in main() after you close it? If it really did close it should throw an IOException. If the close() never finishes you will never reach that line.

Comment: If you debug this program ,you'll found system.in.close() has reached.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is probably blocked on `System.in.close();` - if you add a print statement after that line you will probably see it is never reached.

This is probably because you run it from your IDE which does not allow you to close the console input.

If you run it from the command line, it should work fine.